# Why do I keep getting this error: Error: Email is badly formatted?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I keep getting this error when typing this email address (danidust277@gmail.com) on my website. Why?

HTML:

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" id="update_profile_displayname" placeholder="Display Name"><br></br>
    <input type="email" id="update_profile_email" placeholder="Email Address"><br></br>
    <button type="button" type="submit" id="update_profile_submit">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
var update_email = document.getElementById("update_profile_email");    
var update_name = document.getElementById("update_profile_displayname");

user.updateEmail('update_email').then(function() {    
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
    window.alert(`An error occured:${error}`);  
})
```

Comment: I don't know the library you're using, but I guess `'update_email'` should be `update_email.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `user.updateEmail` is a method that accept as parameter a valid email address. In that case you should not pass the string 'update_email' but the value of your input field, that result in `user.updateEmail(update_email.value)`. Have you already tried this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass `update_email.value` as a param to `user.updateEmail`, just like Davide Bulbarelli says above.